# Need to create an object-level ACL pattern in C#

Tags: c#, security, model-view-controller, acl

I am trying to replicate in plain old C# MVC application the functionality of object-level ACL permissions based on user roles.  Similar to what SharePoint or other CRM/CM systems use.

User have out of the box roles.  So I am all squared away there.

For various objects, like a record of some sort, I would like to have a pattern that looks at your roles, and applies an algo to see if you have access.  Yes or no.

This could no doubt be hard coded in a class somewhere, but I would also like ongoing 'mapping' or other maintenance as roles change or permissions change.

I am envisioning in a business or services layer I just pass your user roles, perhaps invoke some security 'class' and look at the attributes of the object to see if there is a match.

Essentially, there is an 'ACL' on any item, then my roles to determine the things I have access to.

Comment: Is there a question here?